# Как получить конкретное имя ключа в словаре Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Имеется программа, определяющая наименьшее отклонение среднемесячной температуры от средней годовой. Вот сама программа:

```
min=1000
slovar={a:[] for a in range(1,13)} ### Создаём пустой словарь, состоящий из 12-ти ключей (от 1 до 12)
for i in range(366):
  data, temp=input().split() ### Вводим dd.mm t (день.месяц температура) (например 13.09 -11)
  data=int(data[3:5]) ### Мне не нужны дни, их обрезаем
  temp=float(temp)
  slovar[data].append(temp) ### Заполняем словарь по ключу "data" значением "temp"
for i in range(1,13): 
  slovar.update({i:round(sum(slovar[i])/len(slovar[i]), 1)}) ### Находим среднемесячную температуру каждого месяца, заменяем температуру дней на среднюю температуру месяца
avg_y=round(sum(slovar.values())/12, 1) ### Находим среднее за год
for i in range(1,13): 
  if abs(abs(avg_y)-abs(slovar[i]))<min: min=abs(abs(avg_y)-abs(slovar[i]) ### Находим минимальное значение отклонения (ВАЖНО! Поиск минимума сделан так колхозно (не используется операция min), т.к. данная задача формата ЕГЭ (27 номер) и там не очень приветствуются min, avg и тд)
print(avg_y)
mounth=list(slovar.keys()) ### Создаётся список mounth, значения в котором - это ключи словаря slovar (номера месяцев)
for i in range(1, 13):
  if abs(abs(avg_y)-abs(slovar[i]))==min: ### Если отклонение месяца равно минимальному отклонению, то мы его выводим
    print('%02d'%mounth[i-1], '%g'%slovar.get(i), min) ### Выводим номер месяца, температуру, отклонение (Например 09, 10, 5)
```

Возник вопрос, как можно нормально сделать вывод ключа словаря (последние 4 строчки)? Такое ощущение, что можно сделать куда проще. Также можно ли написать `min=abs(abs(avg_y)-abs(slovar[i])` как-то "по-культурнее"? Если есть какие-либо другие советы касательно программы - прошу поделиться. Заранее - всем откликнувшимся огромное спасибо!

Comment: Назовите хоть переменные осмысленными именами, а то читать код очень трудно

Comment: В строчке ``if abs(abs(avg_y)...`` незакрыта скобка. PS. Таких строчек две, в обеих и незакрыта.

Comment: Всё поправил, переменные обозвал

Comment: `<min: min=abs(abs(avg_y)-abs(slovar[i])` а это что за конструкция такая? :)

Comment: Это поиск минимума.  if abs(abs(avg_y)-abs(slovar[i]))<min: (если выражение меньше минимального, то мы присваиваем минимуму значение данного выражения)

Comment: Кстати, а минимуме. Так не надо делать - ``min = 1000``. Для данной задачи так еще сгодится, но в других случаех присвоенное значение может оказаться больше максимального/меньше минимального. Нужно присваивать первое значение из массива, в котором ищется минимум/максимум.

Comment: Благодарю, буду иметь ввиду

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У словарей есть метод `items()`, который возвращает последовательность, состоящую из пар ключ-значение.

```
slovar = {1: 3, 2: 10, 3: 4}

print(type(slovar.items()))
print(slovar.items())

#  <class 'dict_items'>
#  dict_items([(1, 3), (2, 10), (3, 4)])
```

Это примерно то же самое, что список из кортежей:

```
lst = [(1, 3), (2, 4)]

for a, b in lst:
    print('{} - {}'.format(a, b))
```

Можно использовать это в коде:

```
min_value = 10
avg_y = 20
slovar = {1: 3, 2: 10, 3: 4}

for key, value in slovar.items():
    if abs(abs(avg_y) - abs(value)) == min_value:
        print('%02d' % key, '%g' % value, min_value)

        # Результат: 02 10 10
```

Не используйте "min" в качестве имени переменной, потому что такое же имя имеет встроенная и всегда доступная [функция](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#min) - из-за этого могут быть проблемы вроде этой:

```
>>> min(1, 2)
1
>>> min = 10
>>> min(1, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: А можно пожалуйста подробнее узнать "for key, value in slovar.items():..." как вообще данный цикл работает? Можно ли что-то подобное (когда написаны две штучки) использовать не только в словарях?

Comment: Я обновил ответ, добавив пример.